# UploadWebFile SkyDrive .Net API Client

Tags: c#, console-application, onedrive

This is my code for uploading database backup file to SkyDrive. Program is breaking at last line, when it is trying to upload with function `UploadWebFile`. `/Backups` is folder on SkyDrive. I am using SkyDrive .Net API Client 2.0.2b.

Exception is:

> The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

Is it problem with syntax or it is something else, what is solution?

```
var client = new SkyDriveServiceClient();

client.LogOn("username", "password");

WebFolderInfo webInfo = new WebFolderInfo();
webInfo.Path = "/Backups";

client.UploadWebFile(@"D:\db.bak", webInfo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution. Problem was that we cant create WebFolderInfo and give it path manual. We have to reference on folder from  WebFolderInfo[] list. For client.Timeout give it big value for big files to have time to upload.

```
        var client = new SkyDriveServiceClient();

        client.LogOn("username", "password");        
        WebFolderInfo wfInfo = new WebFolderInfo();

        WebFolderInfo[] wfInfoArray = client.ListRootWebFolders();

        wfInfo = wfInfoArray[0];
        client.Timeout = 1000000000;
        client.UploadWebFile(@"D:\db.bak", wfInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's a syntax error, but considering that you're talking baout DB backup, I think it's file dimension problem. The maximum size of the file that you can upload to SkyDrive *should* be something arroung `50MB`.

Check the dimension of your file.

Comment: It is less than 50MB, it is small database.

Comment: I try now with txt file and I got error: The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented.

Comment: @IvanTanasijevic: could be that, at this point, the directory you refer to doesn't exist or relative path pointing to it is not correct ?

Comment: Directory exist but maybe path is not correct. This path I get with WebFolderItemInfo [] infoFolder = client.ListRootWebFolderItems();

Comment: How to find real path for folders, I think that is problem.